# sql select the smaller group

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have the following table with 3 columns. I need to order from lowest to highest by the "apprul_num_sequence" column and stay with the "apprul_cd_fare_rule_bigint" minor. As shown in the second table that would be the expected result. I sense that this is a query with group by and order by but I can not guess. Any ideas?

```
+--------------------------+-------------------+------------------+
|apprul_cd_fare_rule_bigint|apprul_num_sequence|apprul_crr_segment|
+--------------------------+-------------------+------------------+
|                      INNJ|            4999800|                 1|
|                      INNJ|            4999800|                 2|
|                      INNJ|            4999800|                 3|
|                      INNJ|            4999800|                 4|
|                      INNJ|            4999800|                 5|
|                      INNJ|            4999800|                 6|
|                      INNR|            5000000|                 1|
|                      INNR|            5000000|                 2|
|                      LW15|            5004900|                 1|
|                      INNJ|            5005000|                 1|
|                      INNJ|            5005000|                 2|
|                      INNJ|            5005000|                 3|
|                      INNJ|            5005000|                 4|
|                      INNJ|            5005000|                 5|
|                      INNJ|            5005000|                 6|
+--------------------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

The expected result:

```
+--------------------------+-------------------+------------------+
|apprul_cd_fare_rule_bigint|apprul_num_sequence|apprul_crr_segment|
+--------------------------+-------------------+------------------+
|                      INNJ|            4999800|                 1|
|                      INNJ|            4999800|                 2|
|                      INNJ|            4999800|                 3|
|                      INNJ|            4999800|                 4|
|                      INNJ|            4999800|                 5|
|                      INNJ|            4999800|                 6|
|                      INNR|            5000000|                 1|
|                      INNR|            5000000|                 2|
|                      LW15|            5004900|                 1|   
+--------------------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

That is, I have to be with the "apprul_cd_fare_rule_bigint" with the lowest "apprul_num_sequence" if more than one is just as is the case INNJ.

Comment: Are you using mysql or sql server? They are not the same thing.

Comment: "stay with the ... minor"? Huh?

Comment: It is for a program in java, sql

Comment: Stay with INNJ having the smallest sequence, ie INNJ - 4,999,800 and discard INNJ - 5005000

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49e87c/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use a in clause with a subquery

```
select * from my_table
where (apprul_cd_fare_rule_bigint, apprul_num_sequence)
in (select apprul_cd_fare_rule_bigint,  min(apprul_num_sequence) 
        from my_table group by apprul_cd_fare_rule_bigint )
order by apprul_num_sequence
```

Comment: Is that valid syntax in mysql? I have never seen that kind of thing before...of course I can barely spell mysql. In sql server that is not valid syntax. And of course the OP has not made it clear which DBMS they are using. If that is valid it is pretty interesting. I will have to read about that in mysql.

Comment: This is for mysql .. and  yes .. is a valid  sintax in mysql .. but you can obtain also with a join .. i prefer this way because is more easy to understand ..

Comment: I think you're missing a bit, or was that intentional. Note that when using this method you should be careful not to undermine indexes.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you would do this using window function:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by apprul_cd_fare_rule_bigint
                                order by apprul_num_sequence
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

In either database, you can use a correlated subquery in the `where` clause:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.apprul_num_sequence = (select min(t2.apprul_num_sequence)
                               from t t2
                               where t2.apprul_cd_fare_rule_bigint = t.apprul_cd_fare_rule_bigint
                              );
```